# CSS transform of display:table-row cuts off in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Why does the below block cut off in Chrome? I get:

[image]

I'm in Chrome 54.0.2840.59 (the latest per 10/19/2016). It appears that Chrome has issues transforming display:table-row elements? Anyone else encounter this issue / have a workaround?

Thanks!
Matt

```css
#block {
 transform: scale(6);
 display: table-row;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 font-size: 3em;
 background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<div id="block">Block</div>
```

Comment: Possibly, yes. If you use `display:table`, the problem disappears.